# Как сделать так чтобы функция не выполнялась до того момента когда она получит второй параметр

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы функция не выполнялась до того момента, когда она получит второй параметр. Почему-то она у меня начинает выполнятся до того как прейдёт второй параметр. В результате чего появляются ошибки

> (Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli),

Пробовал иссетом и емптино, но увы. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как исправить?

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
$doc=$_POST['doc'];

  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
  if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
    mysqli_select_db($con,"hospital");

   function getChildCategoryList($doc, $id)
 {

  $sql = "SELECT `TIME` FROM reception WHERE `TIME` NOT IN (SELECT TIME FROM doctor WHERE                    doctor.Name_doctor='$doc' AND Data_priema='$id')";

  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  echo "<select name = 'time'>";
  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result )){
echo "<option value=' ".$row2['TIME']." '>".$row2['TIME']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
}
 getChildCategoryList(&$doc,&$id);
```

Comment: **пробовал**

откуда, откуда вообще произошло написание через "ы"?

Comment: @Fike от "быть" имхо, probe слово иностранное, вот к более привычным корням и подгоняем.

Answer (score 4):

`1.` У Вас жестокий и неотвратимый SQL Injection.

```
WHERE doctor.Name_doctor='$doc' AND Data_priema='$id'
```

Рекомендую сразу же, с азов, изучить [PHP PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php).

`2.` название таблицы - `reception` - английское. Поле для имени доктора -  `Name_doctor` - английское. А почему `Data_priema` в транслите? `admission_date` - вот вариант. И почему у Вас полей регистр скачет?

`3.` Не передавайте значения по ссылке. Какой резон?

```
getChildCategoryList(&$doc,&$id); // зачем по ссылке-то?
```

`4.` Ваше сообщение `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli` о первом параметре функции mysqli_query, то есть про переменную $con, которая определена за пределами функции `getChildCategoryList` - она вне контекста, это ж не Javascript. Либо передавайте третьим параметром, либо сделайте из этого всего класс и $con храните как свойство класса

`5.` `"<select name = 'time'>"`    - пробелы в атрибутах не рекомендуются. Должно быть `"<select name='time'>"`

---

Пример работы через PDO

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=hospital', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // вызывать Exception при ошибках

/**
 * @param PDO $db
 * @param mixed $doc
 * @param mixed $id
 */
function getChildCategoryList($db, $doc, $id) {
    if (empty($doc) || empty($id)) // без этих параметров всё равно работать не будет
        return;    
    try {
        $statement = $db->prepare(
            "SELECT `TIME` \
            FROM `reception` \
            WHERE `TIME` NOT IN ( \
                    SELECT TIME \
                    FROM doctor \
                    WHERE doctor.Name_doctor=? AND Data_priema=? -- здесь использовать подстановки \
                ) \
            ");
        $statement->execute(array($doc,$id)); // параметры в порядке использования в запросе

            echo "<select name = 'time'>";
            while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) // возвращать результаты в виде массивов
            {
                echo "<option value=' ".$row['TIME']." '>".$row['TIME']."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
    } catch(Exception $e)  {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

$id = isset($_POST['id'])?$_POST['id']:false;
$doc = isset($_POST['doc'])?$_POST['doc']:false;

getChildCategoryList($db, $doc, $id);
```

Comment: напишите пожалуйста как это должно выглядеть

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev зачем вообще нужен класс, который вы тут нарисовали ?

Comment: Действительно, зачем. Переписал.

Comment: спасибо за помощ,но увы либо $id либо $doc всёравно выполняют запрос не ждя при этом второго значения в результате чего ответ не верный( может мне всётаки прислать хтмл форму?

Comment: а вот так?
    
    function getChildCategoryList($db, $doc, $id) {
        if (empty($doc) || empty($id)) // без этих параметров всё равно работать не будет
            return;
    ...

а вообще такие ситуации разруливаются в пошаговой отладке